# The address in Kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I have a question when I located the address in kernel. I insert a hello module in kernel, in this module, I put these things:

```
char mystring[]="this is my address";
printk("<1>The address of mystring is %p",virt_to_phys(mystring));
```

I think I can get the physical address of mystring, but what I found is, in syslog, the printed address of it is 0x38dd0000. However, I dumped the memory and found the real address of it is dcd2a000, which is quite different from the former one. How to explain this? I did something wrong? Thanks

PS: I used a tool to dump the whole memory, physical addresses.

Comment: When you "dumped the memory", you didn't get virtual addresses there?

Comment: The memory I dumped is physical address, I used a tool

Comment: what is the hardware platform ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Man page of VIRT_TO_PHYS](http://mirror.linux.org.au/linux.conf.au/2005/cdrom-beta-1/linux-mandocs-2.6.12.6/virt_to_phys.html)

> The returned physical address is the physical (CPU) mapping for the memory address given. **It is only valid to use this function on addresses directly mapped or allocated via kmalloc.**
>
> This function does not give bus mappings for DMA transfers. In almost all conceivable cases a device driver should not be using this function

Try allocating the memory for `mystring` using `kmalloc` first;

```
char *mystring = kmalloc(19, GFP_KERNEL);
strcpy(mystring, "this is my address"); //use kernel implementation of strcpy
printk("<1>The address of mystring is %p", virt_to_phys(mystring));
kfree(mystring);
```

Here is an implementation of strcpy found [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/lib/string.c#L70):

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *tmp = dest;

    while ((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0')
            /* nothing */;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I used like this but there are errors, first is kmalloc should have two arguments, so I added GEL_KERNEL, second is in the strcpy line, I think `strcpy` is not accepted...so how can I solve it, thanks

Comment: Haha, woops! Sorry, it's been about 6 months since I've touched the kernel. As far as strcpy goes, you should be able to `#include <string.h>`, if your kernel source provides one. Or you can write your own.

Comment: thanks !a lot! But when I make it, two errors also, one is `char *mystring = kmalloc(19, GFP_KERNEL);` error is `initializer element is not constant`, another is `strcpy(mystring, "this is my address");` command, the error is `expected ')' before string constant` I already added the strcpy function you wrote here, thanks!!