# no heap allocated memory (kernel address)

Tags: kernel, malloc, heap-memory, object-address

I have a question when I located the address in kernel. I insert a hello module in kernel, in this module, I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959225/the-address-in-kernel).

For now I can use `kmalloc` to achieve the address by `virt_to_phys`.

```
char *mystring = kmalloc(19, GFP_KERNEL);
strcpy(mystring, "this is my address"); 
printk("<1>The address of mystring is %p", virt_to_phys(mystring));
```

But I want to know how to find the address of `char mystring[]="this is my address";`. This is no heap allocated memory, right? How to find it by some functions?

PS: I used a tool to dump the whole memory, physical addresses.

Comment: Stack addresses are still virtual memory addresses. Kernel thread stacks really aren't any different from any other memory, they're allocated form the "heap" (if you can call it that) as well.

Comment: Okay, but I cannot use `virt_to_phys` to find the address of mystring, the printed address is not matched.

Comment: If you've got `char str[]="some string";` in a function, the function will allocate stack memory to hold the string, and then usually copy the string from a data segment. If you're taking a memory image, you're probably detecting the copy of the string in the data segment, not the one on the stack, yet you're looking up the physical address of the stack copy.